# How to print the following elements in a a given string?

Tags: java, string

Given an input:

> a3b4c5

Output should be:

> aaabbbbccccc

How i did this program?

I have a string from user as given in the input and then checked whether its alphabet first.
If it's a alphabet, increment till it reaches its counter number to which it is to be printed.
I tried to produce the same output, but i am getting a following line as output.

Output shown:

> 

**Code:**

```
public class Pattern
{
    public static void main(String s[]) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s1 = br.readLine();
        char ch[] = s1.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < ch.length;) {
            if ((ch[i] <= 65) || (ch[i] >= 90)) {
                i++;
            } else if ((ch[i] <= 97) || (ch[i] >= 122)) {
                i++;
            } else {
                if (ch[i] == '0' || ch[i] == '1' || ch[i] == '2'
                        || ch[i] == '3' || ch[i] == '4' || ch[i] == '5'
                        || ch[i] == '6' || ch[i] == '7' || ch[i] == '8'
                        || ch[i] == '9') {
                    for (int p = 0; p < ch[i]; p++) {
                        System.out.println(ch[i - 1]);

                    }
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ouch , `if(ch[i]=='0'||ch[i]=='1'||ch[i]=='2'||ch[i]=='3'||ch[i]=='4'||ch[i]=='5'||ch[i]=='6'||ch[i]=='7'||ch[i]=='8'||ch[i]=='9')` this looks awkward. Any better choice?

Comment: @Raptor yes raptor thats awful but first Focus on the output i need to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are taking the inequalities right and you are not taking the right boolean operators. Also, you need a `print` and not a `println` and a `println` at the very end. You should have something like this.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.NumberFormatException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class t1

{
    public static void main(String s[]) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s1 = br.readLine();
        char ch[] = s1.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < ch.length;) {
            if ((ch[i] >= 65) && (ch[i] <= 90)) {
                i++;
            } else if ((ch[i] >= 97) && (ch[i] <= 122)) {
                i++;
            } else {
                if (ch[i] >= '0' && ch[i] <= '9') {
                    for (int p = 0; p < ch[i]-'0'; p++) {
                        System.out.print(ch[i - 1]);

                    }
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Not understood ch[i]-'0' logic

Comment: to get the number. Since we already know that it is a digit and the digit are ordered in the list of char, substracting the digit zero `0` give you exactly the number of time to output the char. I wanted to keep it as close as possible to your original code.

Comment: Can u five me an example? for example if i said a3b3 then 3 is a character.0 is subtracted to make it integer.Otherwise it is taking ascii value and printing as many times Right?

Comment: @javaCoderMakeSimple Do you want to be able to repeat a character more than 9 times?

Comment: `ch="a3b3"` is a `String`, when you take `ch[0]`, you get the `char '3'`, `ch[1]` is the `char '3'`. `char` in java are like `integer`. In the order of `char`, let say ascii ordering, all the digit char are ordered. you get them in the order `'0', '1', '2', '3'`, etc. When you do `ch[1]-'0'`, you get the same result as the difference between the order of `'3'` and the order of `'0'`, which is exactly what we want.

Comment: @Shar1er80, of course, it will not work for numbers larger than 9.  What I wanted to do is to point to what is making the code not working. My goal was not to improve it. Have to do it one step at a time. I want those who ask question to get answers and to understand too; this is very important and I learned that while teaching!

Answer (score 3):

**Example code:**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Pattern
{
    public static void main(String s[]) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Enter input string: ");
        String inputStr = br.readLine();

        ArrayList<String> stringParts = new ArrayList<>();
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\D+|\\d+").matcher(inputStr);
        while (matcher.find())
        {
            stringParts.add(matcher.group());
        }

        // Just to view the contents
        System.out.println("stringParts: " + Arrays.toString(stringParts.toArray()));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < stringParts.size(); i += 2) {
            for(int j = 0; j < Integer.parseInt(stringParts.get(i + 1)); j++) {

                sb.append(stringParts.get(i));
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Output: " + sb.toString());
    }
}
```

**Input/Output:**

```
Enter input string: a3b4c5
stringParts: [a, 3, b, 4, c, 5]
Output: aaabbbbccccc

Enter input string: ab2cd3
stringParts: [ab, 2, cd, 3]
Output: ababcdcdcd

Enter input string: abc1def2xyz3
stringParts: [abc, 1, def, 2, xyz, 3]
Output: abcdefdefxyzxyzxyz
```

- Using a pattern matcher, split the input string into chunks of alphabets and digits
- Use a string builder to append them accordingly

Note:

This should be some form of [Run-length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding), or decoding in this case.

Comment: Interesting solution, but it's a bit much for what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: @blasko If you try ab2cd3, it won't actually work since the current solution assumes the pattern to be repeated is only one character.

Comment: That is true, but wasn't specified in the original question so I didn't handle it in my snippet. If that is what the OP is looking for, then he would want to go the route of what you did.

Comment: @blasko Yup, so I guess this would just be an alternative answer. It would work for the question as it is, but also for the more general case. I guess it all depends on his preference. :)

Answer (score 2):

This should fix your problem

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
char ch[] = br.readLine().toCharArray();

for (int i = 1; i < ch.length; i++) {
    if (Character.isDigit(ch[i])) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ch[i]-'0'; j++) {
            System.out.print(ch[i-1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Basically by having the single if statement that checks whether ch[i] is a digit or not, you avoid having to do all of your other checks. If ch[i] is a digit, convert it to an integer by subtracting the character '0' from it. The rest should make sense.

Comment: Why ch[i]-'0' ? i haven't understood that part

Comment: It's subtracting the ASCII value of the digit 0 from the value of the given digit, in order to get a proper integer. Refer to [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: @Gosu Can u five me an example? for example if i said a3b3 then 3 is a character.0 is subtracted  to make it integer.Otherwise it is taking ascii value and printing as many times Right?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an shorter example using `regex` and capture groups.  This is on the assumption that sometimes you can have a pattern where there's a string that doesn't have a number following it.

For example:

```
a2bc3 => aabccc
```

The regex pattern:

```
"(\\D+)(\\d*)"
```

Pattern breakdown:

- `(\\D+)` - captures 1 or more non-digit characters into capture group 1
- `(\\d*)` - captures 0 or more digits characters into capture group 2

Use a `StringBuilder` to build the output.

Convert capture group 2 to an integer, if group 2 has data, so you know how many times to repeat group 1 in the results.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<String> inputs = new ArrayList() {{
       add("a3b4c5");
       add("a3bc5");
       add("a3bc");
       add("abc");
       add("ab3cd4ef5");
       add("a10bc1e10");
    }};

    for (String input : inputs) {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\\D+)(\\d*)").matcher(input);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String group1 = matcher.group(1);
            String group2 = matcher.group(2);

            int loopCount = 0;
            if (!group2.isEmpty()) {
                loopCount = Integer.parseInt(group2);
            }

            // Always print the group at least once
            output.append(group1);
            // Possibly print more
            for (int i = 1; i < loopCount; i++) {
                output.append(group1);
            }   
        }
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

Results:

```
aaabbbbccccc
aaabcbcbcbcbc
aaabc
abc
abababcdcdcdcdefefefefef
aaaaaaaaaabceeeeeeeeee
```

Answer (score 1):

The first two if statements mean you'll skip anything less than or equal to 
97 or greater than or equal to 90: so you'll skip every possible value.

You probably just want to use `Character.isLetter()` and `Character.isDigit()`.

Also, `p < ch[i]` should be `p < (Integer.valueOf("" + ch[i]))`; otherwise 1 will print 49 copies.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying like this, it may not be the best one but you can try with this

```
   String st="A3B4C5";
    String st1="";
    int l=0;
    char ar[]=st.toCharArray();
    char c='0';
    for(int i=0;i<ar.length;i++){
    if(Character.isLetter(ar[i])){
    c=ar[i];
        }
    else if(Character.isDigit(ar[i])) {
     l=Character.getNumericValue(ar[i]);     
    for(int j=0;j<l;j++){
    System.out.print(c);
    }   
        }

    }
```